# I want the second menu to be at media

Tags: html, css

I want to display the second menu only at the mobile but the code doesn't respond.

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .branding {
    background: red!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="branding">
  <div class="branding2">
    <div class="logo_main">
      <a href="http://#.gr/"><img class=" preload-me" src="http://#.gr/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo-#-small.png" srcset="http://#.gr/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo-#-small.png 350w, http://#.gr/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/logo-#-big.png 600w" width="350" height="73" sizes="350px"
          alt="Studio Alex"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_main">
      <ul style="list-style:none;" id="primary-menu" class="main-nav underline-decoration upwards-line outside-item-remove-margin" role="menu">
        <li style=" float:left;" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-146 first"><a style="display:block;text-align:center;padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none;" href="http://#.gr/?page_id=141" data-level="1"><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Photography</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="float:left;" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a style="display:block;text-align:center;padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none;" href="http://#.gr/?page_id=61" data-level="1"><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Cinematography</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="float:left;" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-445"><a style="display:block;text-align:center;padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none;" href="http://#.gr/?page_id=442" data-level="1"><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Contact</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="float:left;" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-567"><a style="display:block;text-align:center;padding:14px 16px; text-decoration:none;" href="http://#.gr/" data-level="1"><span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-text">Home</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to `display:none` the mobile version on desktop and display block on mobile. I typed the code but it doesn't read the media command. Any ideas?

Comment: Either you forgot the `<style>` start tag, or you just haven't created a real [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the max width of what.
Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .branding {
      background:red!important;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Like Quentin suggested in the comments: Either your code example is not complete, or you forgot a `<style>` start-tag.

Comment: What exactly de you want to happen? I just read you question again and got kinda confused. You said it did not read the media query, but in you media query it does not say anything about the `display`. Is this also supposed to change when the screen gets smaller?

Comment: i used background:red; just for example. I have 2 menus and i want in Desktop the 1st menu and in mobile the 2nd. BUT it doesnt read any of the media commands....

Comment: "You dont specifie the max width of what" — You don't need to.

Comment: If you go to this fiddle and run it. Shrink the results screen you will see that the background turns red. I have also tidied up the html for you. You had a missing <style> and an extra </div> - https://jsfiddle.net/dg8kehnu/